# how to add row in datagrid dynamically

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I am using WPF application 
in this form have one gridview and one button

i am using the ObservableCollection have Generic and one class code like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public ObservableCollection<gm> data1 = new ObservableCollection<gm>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
      //  public ObservableCollection<gm> data { get { return data1; } }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

           data1.Add(new gm() { no = 2, name = "vipul" });
           dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data1.ToArray();
        }
    }
    public class gm
    {
        public int no { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

when i am execute above code it add blank row in datagrid 
please give me solution of this problem 
i want to know how to add row in datagird run time.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

set autogeneratecolumns to true and just set data1 as itemssource

xaml

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

EDIT: to get the power of WPF look into DataBinding/MVVM

Answer (score 0):

XAML is like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

code behind is this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = data1;
}
```

and remove this line:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data1.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data1.Add(new gm { no = 2, name = "vipul" }); // Remore ellipsis around gm.
```

In XAML just check the following that

1. You have DataSource of your datagrid to `{Binding Path="data1"}`
2. DataColumn of no have binding to `{Binding Path="no"}`
3. DataColumn of name have binding path to `{Binding Path="name"}`